# Create markdown frequency table using weights in R

Tags: r

Suppose I have some data that looks like this:

```
df1 = data.frame(id=c("A1","A2","A3","A4"), 
                 variable=as.factor(c("black", "black", "blue", "no answer")),
                 weight=c(3,3,4,2))
```

I want to create a markdown table that takes into account the weights. Right now I'm doing the following:

```
library(knitr)
kable(as.data.frame(table(df1$variable)/nrow(df1)), format = "markdown")
```

which gives me the relative freq without taking into account the weights. On addition to using the weights I would like to add a column to the table with the absolute frequency.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this solution:

```
d <- aggregate(weight~variable,df1,sum) # calculate occurences

d$freqs <- d$weight/sum(d$weight) # calculate freqs

kable(d)
```

The output is:

```
|variable  | weight|     freqs|
|:---------|------:|---------:|
|black     |      6| 0.5000000|
|blue      |      4| 0.3333333|
|no answer |      2| 0.1666667|
```

[**Update**]

Alternatively, you can use the `dplyr` package:

```
library(dplyr)

df1 %>% 
    group_by(variable) %>%
    summarise(abs.freqs=sum(weight)) %>%
    mutate(freqs=abs.freqs/sum(df1$weight)) %>%
    kable()
```

which has a more wordy syntax but every step is pretty much self-explaining (%>% is a piping operator that uses expression on the left side as a first argument of the expression on the right side).
The output is:

```
|variable  | abs.freqs|     freqs|
|:---------|---------:|---------:|
|black     |         6| 0.5000000|
|blue      |         4| 0.3333333|
|no answer |         2| 0.1666667|
```